# Какой знак препинания необходим?

Tags: пунктуация

Не судите строго это моя первая картина.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Возможны несколько вариантов:

1. Не судите строго! Это моя первая картина.
2. Не судите строго, это моя первая картина. *или* !
3. Не судите строго: это моя первая картина. *или* !
4. Не судите строго — это моя первая картина. *или* !

Answer (score 0):

Возможны также варианты с интонационным тире.
Как пример:
***Это — гигант мысли, отец русской демократии и особа, приближенная к императору.***
(И. Ильф, Е. Петров. Двенадцать стульев)

Не судите строго... это — моя первая картина.
Не судите строго, это — моя первая картина.
Не судите строго: это — моя первая картина.

Все зависит от *интонации* и от того, *какой смысл* Вы хотите вложить в свое предложение.